# `onReady` not firing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    alert("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady Fired");     //This works

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        //height: '390',
        //width: '640',
        videoId: buni_php_params.videoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

    }
// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    alert("onPlayerReady Fired");               // This doesn't
    event.target.playVideo();
    }
```

The video loads and plays.

http://wppagoda.pagodabox.com/?p=1

I have a standard wordpress install for a plugin I'm making, it fetches a videoID from database (`buni_php_params.videoId`) and plays it. But the event onPlayerReady is never fired.… even though `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is fired.

Comment: okay, this is weird, I just opened it up in a private tab and it WORKS! I have no idea why or how...

Comment: Clear your cache. If you are on Chrome, you can disable cache in the debugger settings.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a problem of a function not being loaded I go for the `window.myFunction` approach rathen than just `myFunction`. This proved to be more portable between browsers as well.

Answer (score -1):

well i dont want to sound an idiot, but it seems like you should add "()" to your `onPlayerReady` in the `'onReady': onPlayerReady,`

So: `'onReady': onPlayerReady(),`  You're calling a function after all.

I might be wrong.

Comment: I think he's making an assignment there, so referencing the function, not invoking it. I might be wrong as well.

Comment: Then i assume he should pass the event to the function, but i am not very familiar with YT API.